# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Tags: javascript

There is some problem regarding the promise which I cant see when I type in something for example 'pizza' in the search bar and hit search.Console output looks like that: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

I tried to look for any misspelling but couldn't find anything.

it's my github repo: https://github.com/damianjnc/forkifyApp

Anyone can see what causing the error?

Comment: **Unclear what you are asking.** Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had bad css classes in your `base.js` file:

```
export const elements = {
    searchForm: document.querySelector('.search'),
    searchInput: document.querySelector('.search__field'),
    searchResList: document.querySelector('.results__list')
}
```

Be carefull of the class name, you just forgot the double "_" between "search" and "field". Same for "results__list".

Comment: yes, it sorted value of null problem but straight after that I got that error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined, I changed to double __ here results__list but its still says that it's undefined